# Pyro4 Python “socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable”

Tags: python, sockets, pyro

I am having a weird error in a Python/Pyro4 application, I am using two Microsoft Windows machines, one using Windows 7 and the other one using 8.1, connected via Ethernet; first I register both Pyro objects in the name server, one using a "Root" tag in the nameserver, and the other one with a "Handler" tag, first the app acquires the proxy "Root" object and uses is without problem, but when it is time to call a method contained in the "Handler" object it gives the

```
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable problem...
```

I start each component(Pyro object) in a separate thread, any help appreciated as to what is going on here, as soon as I can i'll post some of the code.

Comment: Most likely the internal firewall is blocking it.

Comment: You might want to add retires. I am running on Google cloud and 99/100 times email is sent on first attempt...